# How to get execution details in Oracle Data Integrator

Tags: oracle, email, oracle-data-integrator

I have written a code using procedure to send an email in Jython. Now I have put my procedure inside a package and I am running the package.

However, what I need to get is the package name, start time of execution of package and end time of execution of package and send it via email.

I tried using [getPrevStepLog](http://gerardnico.com/doc/odi/webhelp/en/ref_api/getprevsteplog.htm) but that isn't working

My procedure code as of now:

```
import smtplib
import string
BODY = string.join((
"From: %s" % 'test@gmail.com',
"To: %s" % 'admin@odi.com',
"Subject: %s" % 'Mail From ODI',
"",
'This is a mail from ODI Studio. Thank You.Previous step 
'<%=odiRef.getPrevStepLog("STEP_NAME")%>' executed in    
'<%=odiRef.getPrevStepLog("DURATION")%>' seconds'
 ), "\r\n")
 sender = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
 sender.set_debuglevel(1)
 sender.ehlo()
 sender.starttls()
 sender.ehlo()
 sender.login('test', 'test123')
 sender.sendmail('test@gmail.com',['admin@odi.com'],BODY)
 sender.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use the function getSession ?

```
public java.lang.String getSession(java.lang.String pPropertyName)

pPropertyName

SESS_NO = internal session ID
SESS_NAME = session name
SCEN_VERSION = version of current scenario
CONTEXT_NAME = name of the execution context
CONTEXT_CODE = code of the execution context
AGENT_NAME = name of the physical agent
SESS_BEG = date and hour of the begining of the session
USER_NAME = Oracle Data Integrator user executing the session
```

Exemple : to get the current session name

```
<%=odiRef.getSession("SESS_NAME")%>
```